# Store node relationships counting the number of them

Tags: java, graph

In a Java application I need an structure to store, lets call them nodes, and the number of relationship with other nodes. For example, I would need to know that node A is related with B 3 times.

Thinking in a way to implement this I got to this possible solution: Have a hashmap using nodes as key and another hashmap as value. This hashmap would store nodes as key (node B in the example) and an integer as value representing the number of relationships.

What do you think about this? Is it a good approach?

If so, I have a question. Suppose tha I store strings and they come from a text file after apply String.split function. Now I store "hello" in the first hashmap but after processing the file, this string appears as a destiny node in the second hashmap. Would these strings have a reference to the same object or I'll have multiple copies of the same objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question, I would do something similar but different. Instead of creating a `Hashmap` inside a `Hashmap` I would create a new class `Relationship` that looks something like this:

```
public class NodeRelationship {
    private Node relatedNode;
    private int numOfRelations

    // Constructor + getters and setters
}
```

And define your map like this: `Map<Node, List<NodeRelationship>>` This seems more readable to me (but maybe it's just me) and easier to later expend. For example if you iterate on the list and want to know the original node you can add a member `parent` to `NodeRelationshio` and so on.

Regarding the second question - it depends on how you create your objects and whether you create new objects or use existing ones. If you have a node `hello` that you put in your value `Hashmap` (or in the `List` in my solution) and you use the same object for creating a new key - so there's no duplication. If you don't have a way (or just don't search for) to know that the node was already created, and you create new node - then you'll have duplications of objects.

If indeed your each of your nodes is created from text string, you can maintain a new `Map<String, Node>` and in the process of reading the file you can maintain this map and check if an object exists before creating a new one. This is very low cost in performance and you can get rid of the map once the construction of the objects from text is done.

Comment: I like your solution but, wouldn't be slower? With hashmap I have O(1) in nodr searches but with lists I would have O(n).

Comment: I guess that if you have more than 1-2 (maybe 3) such relationship with different nodes then you right.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía Maybe you can use `NodeRelationship` as a class that holds the inner hash map. I just don't like to see a map inside a map. Very unreadable

Comment: Yes, I could do that but would be the same. I couldn't use the referenced node to do a quick search over the hashmap. Maybe overriding equals in Relationship to use the stored node for comparitions.